# Novels about a male cyborg space ship captain with a female feline humanoid business partner

Tags: story-identification, novel

I can't remember the titles of the novels. I read two novels in the series, in approximately 1991. The novels centered on a group of 4 individuals who have a small spaceship. The captain was a male cyborg and another of the main characters was a female feline humanoid. The novels contained a number of allusions to Shakespearean plays.

Comment: Hmm, search results for these books seem to be turning up mainly erotic novels for some reason. Not entirely sure why so many of these novels apparently include cyborg captains. Something to do with being battery operated, perhaps?

Comment: Is there any chance you are slightly mis-remembering Poul Anderson's Trader Team stories?  The characters are David Falkayn, a human, Che Lan a female alien from a very cat-like species, Adzel a male alien from a vaguely dragon-like species, and the ship's computer, the Muddlin' Through.  There are 3-4 novels/story collections featuring them.

Comment: @John Cashew: Did you get a chance to check out DavidW's answer?

Answer (score 3):

I'm having a great deal of difficulty digging up details on these books, and I don't own them (I borrowed them from a cousin in 1985) but I suspect you may be thinking of [*Doom Star*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?16330) (1978) and [*Doom Star Number Two*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?927907) (1979) by Richard S. Meyers.

At the beginning of the first book the *Black Hole* has a crew of two:  **captain Larry Baker, a cyborg** and his partner Napoleon, a **humanoid feline woman**.  They pick up Harlan (Hal), a soldier/police officer with a space-going combat suit (space bullet) to pull off a rescue mission.  (The woman they're rescuing might be the fourth member of the party you recall.)

In the second book they join up with a **travelling Shakespeare company**.

([Google books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Return_to_Doomstar/Ho5pHQAACAAJ?hl=en) says: "Larry Baker, Napoleon, and Harlan join the Light Orbit Space Theatre, a space traveling Shakespearean troupe, and are soon in a battle with their old insect-like enemies, the Mantases")

The books were republished as *Doomstar* and *Return to Doomstar* (1985) under the name Richard Meyers.

[image: Cover of Doom Star (1978)]
[image: Cover of Doom Star Number Two (1979)]

[image: Cover of Doomstar (1985)]
[image: Cover of Return to Doomstar (1985)]